# Add sunflare kind of lighting effect on image

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, opengl-es, gpuimage

I am looking for sunflare kind of lighting effect on Image. In my case light source is bulb instead of Sun. And I understand that changing light source changes rays effect and even different type of bulb produces different type of light beams.

Here is an example of focus light : http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/focus-light/

I have looked into standard photo filters and OpenCV but we didn't find something obvious. I am looking for approach and direction to achieve it.

My knowledge is limited to iOS business apps only. I have heard only name of frameworks like OpenGL,SceneKit and MetalKit.So, I would prefer to have solution which fits into my knowledge stack but yes I would love to know all possible solutions.

Let me know if you want me to explain more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `light effect of torch over a texture` is vague, if you can give a picture here may help you.

Comment: Maybe this can do the trick: generate a gaussian kernel, at the desired position, add the values of the gaussian kernel to the original image to simulate a bright spot.

Comment: click EDIT and actually put some images in your question. Nobody has the time to click links.